# Foods for the family before Pesach, when pesadika?

Tags: food, passover, how-to

As challenging as it may be to feed a family with kids of all ages during Pesach, it is harder in the days before Pesach when the kitchen is hametz-free and matza sandwiches, matza pizza, matza lasangna, and the like are not an option.  Since we use so many eggs on the hag, we are trying to avoid eggs beforehand.  To make it harder, the family is vegetarian.

What filling, kid friendly foods do you suggest for those days?

Comment: I'm not sure how many days you are struggling with. Do you turn your kitchen over a week in advance? Do you live in an area with restaurants? Do your little kids like egg matzah? [is this even on topic?]

Comment: What wrong with Matza sandwiches for kids? If you don't want to use matza you can always use the gluten free matza crackers. Or cook chicken and rice. Most of the world lives on rice every day

Comment: Matza ball soup? Hamburgers and hotdogs on store bought buns? The options are endless. Salmon? French fries? Lentil soup? Cheese omelette? Scrambled eggs? Green beans? Cholent? Other stews? Tuna and corn chips? We don't know your kids' preferences or your kitchen set up so it's nigh impossible to really answer this question without more details

Comment: @DoubleAA  Your answer implies that matza balls do not fall under the prohibition of eating matza before the seder, which is correct.  What store bought buns are you referring to?  Hametz? If not hametz, what are they made of?

Comment: @YehudaW Chametz buns. Don't eat them in your kitchen and it's all fine. Store bought just means you don't have to bake them. You could even make PB&J on the porch or in designated side area. Do you see how the possibilities are endless? Also, maybe instead of banning eggs before the holiday, it would make more sense to eat them before and ban them during when you have other Matza based options.

Comment: Per ^^^, when my kids would inevitably track food all around the house despite my warning them that the house was set up for Pesach, I banished them to eating outside the house. Yes, they whine and complain that it's cold outside and they don't like it. Too bad for them. Eventually, they learn discipline, and when they mature they understand why I do it this way, and they just follow the routine. If they still don't like it, they "starve" for a few weeks.

Comment: How about freshly cut fruits and vegetables? You can't go wrong with those. I find an apple quite filling for a snack.

Comment: Fruits are good snacks, but not really a main dish.

Answer (score 1):

[Quick vegetable curry](http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipe/706/quick-vegetable-curry.aspx) with mashed potatoes or baked potatoes or matza balls.